# Pattern for using websockets (via socket.io) only on demand for mobile application

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a mobile application that will *sometimes* need near real time updates, so I'm looking to use websockets when necessary.  Some early testing seems to show that maintaining a using a websocket all the time keeps the data connection on my phone open constantly, causing faster batter drain.

So I'm thinking it will be more battery efficient to use regular ajax style requests most of the time and only use websockets when necessary.

I'm new to socket.io - does it provide any means to manually "downgrade" connections?  If not I will want a communication layer on top of it - can anyone suggest a layer on top of socket.io that would allow me to manually switch between websocket and regular ajax connections?

Comment: Have you also considered just closing and reopening the websockets when needed? I'm pretty sure that should be as battery efficient (if not more) as polling with XHR calls.

Comment: Actually... no, I didn't think of that.  So my pattern would just be to close the socket when I don't need "real-time" connection.  I'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I"m not sure what kind of layer you want or what you think the requirements are for such a layer?

For a webSocket, you can just open it from the client when you want it on and then close it from the client when you no longer need it.  As long as you keep an open/closed flag or just a null/non-null socket variable, you will know whether to use it because it's already open or just issue an ajax call if it isn't open.

It would be up to your application to know when it wanted more real-time updates and it should open the webSocket and when it no longer needed realtime updates so it can close the socket.  That is entirely application logic that you haven't described an application-specific algorithm for so there isn't a whole lot we can suggest there without a detailed set of requirements.

You are correct that an open webSocket will use more battery than only doing occasional ajax calls.  That's because a socket.io webSocket will send regular keep-alive messages every few minutes so both client and server can know when the connection has died and must be re-established.  This regular transmission does cost battery.  So, if you compare that to an ajax call only every 15 minutes, the ajax call will consume less battery.  On the other hand, if you need real-time type updates so you'd be issuing an ajax call every 15 seconds to try to poll for the real-time behavior, then a webSocket would be more efficient than that because the server can just send the data when needed without the client regular polling for it.  So, it really depends upon the usage pattern and how real-time-ish you need your updates.

I could imagine a client-side function like this:

```
 // variable that keeps track of when we have an open webSocket connection
 // null means no webSocket currently open, non-null means active webSocket

 var socket;

 // private helper function, don't call directly
 function _openSocket(msg, data) {
     if (!socket) {
         // establish webSocket
         socket = io();
         socket.on('connect', function() {
             if (msg) {
                  socket.emit(msg, data);
             }
         });
         socket.on('disconnect', function() {
             socket = null;
         });
     }
 }

 // send some data now
 function sendData(msg, data, openContinuous) {
     if (socket) {
         // webSocket already open
         socket.emit(msg, data);
     } else if (openContinuous) {
         _openSocket(msg, data);
     } else {
         // send data via ajax call
         $.ajax(...);
     }
 }

 // open a continuous connection (e.g. a socket.io connection) 
 // if not already open
 function openContinuous() {
     if (!socket) {
         _openSocket();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Added a sample function that would send data over whichever transport was desired and available.